# Retrieve information using ElementTree

Tags: python, openstreetmap, elementtree

I try to retrieve the information using ElementTree. I succeeded in retrieving for many attributes but the processing stops maybe for lack of information. It displays this error message :

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Here is the code I use :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

MyosmID = str(id_cinema)
r = requests.get("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/"+MyosmID)
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)

for child in root.iter('tag'):
    if child.attrib['k'] == 'website':
        website = child.attrib['v']
    if child.attrib['k'] == 'wikidata':
        wikidata = child.attrib['v']
```

How can I solve this error case?

Comment: Add the following lines before you call `fromstring`: `print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)`; or, alternatively, just `r.raise_for_status()` if you want to raise an error on an invalid response.

Comment: I suspect you are getting a 404 not found response, as I similarly do when I test with `MyosmID = '12345'`

Comment: when I test with MyosmID = '630982183'
 of the attribute that potentially blocks the processing I get the same error message above (in my question)

Comment: I am getting a different error with that input. `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 410 Client Error: Gone for url: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/630982183`

Comment: You should first add the line `r.raise_for_status()`, as i suggested above. Otherwise, the server could tell you that the request was invalid, but in your code you're assuming the request was a success, which is not always true.

Comment: when I do it I get a 410 error too: Requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 410 Client Error: Gone for url: https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/630982183

Comment: Does this mean that the query for all attributes is invalid or only for this attribute?

Comment: Yes, when i visit that link in a browser, I get the same response. Also, compare against something like https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/123 which seems to be valid.

Comment: I think it is invalid only for that given node.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my code and the problem is solved :

```
    MyosmID = str(id_cinema)
try : 
    r = requests.get("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/"+MyosmID)
    r.raise_for_status()
    root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)
    
    fromstring: print(r.status_code) 
    
    for child in root.iter('tag'):
        if child.attrib['k'] == 'website':
            website = child.attrib['v']
        if child.attrib['k'] == 'wikidata':
            wikidata = child.attrib['v']
except Exception:
    pass
```

Thank you for your help :)